# Login to laravel vapor in codebuild using api key

Tags: laravel, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, cicd, laravel-vapor

I am attempting to do a CI/CD pipeline for a laravel vapor application using AWS codepipeline and code build.
Since deploying to vapor just requires running the vapor deploy command, I figured I could run that command on my codebuild image. Problem is that vapor requires authentication prompt using `vapor login` command. Would it be possible to authenticate vapor using API key generated on the vapor dashboard? this way, I could deploy using a push to a specific branch. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to set VAPOR_API_TOKEN environment variable and it authenticated